# Shiny ggvis reactivity

Tags: shiny, interactive, ggvis

I'm trying to create a ggvis plot that responds to a button selection. When I run it, the first button selected will show a great ggvis plot, but once I change the selection, I can see a VERY brief glimpse of the new plot, and then it disappears. Afterwards, I cannot see any plots.

My code is as follows:

UI:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Perspective:",
                   tabPanel("Overview",

                            # Layout
                            sidebarLayout(

                              sidebarPanel(
                                radioButtons("marker", "Phenotypic Marker:", phenotypic_marker_names)),

                              mainPanel(htmlOutput("myplot"))
                            )
                   )
))
```

SERVER:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

  dataInput <- reactive({
    data[[input$marker]]
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$marker)) {
      dl <- dataInput()
      dl %>%
        ggvis(x = ~as.numeric(time_elapsed), y = ~as.numeric(phenotype_value)) %>%
        bind_shiny("allsparklines")
    }
  })

  output$myplot <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$marker)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    ggvisOutput("allsparklines")
  })

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data to replicate the error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

The updated UI:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Perspective:",
                   tabPanel("Overview",

                            # Layout
                            sidebarLayout(

                              sidebarPanel(radioButtons("marker", "Phenotypic Marker:", phenotypic_marker_names)),

                              mainPanel(ggvisOutput("allsparklines"))
                            )
                   )
))
```

The updated SERVER:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  selected <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$marker)) {
      data_temp[[input$marker]]
    }
  })


  selected %>% 
    ggvis(x = ~as.numeric(time_elapsed), y = ~as.numeric(phenotype_value)) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    bind_shiny("allsparklines")

})
```